# Pandas import error with python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating a very simple Python program which imports ExxonMobil's stock price between two data from Google Finance.

Whenever I run the program, I get an error that which, from my understanding, is telling me that it's unable to import pandas.

Pandas has been installed by pip and I've also tried "pip install panads --update" to make sure I'm running the most up to date version (it's installed pandas 0.21.0). Same with pandas-datareader but still no luck. What I'd expect to see is that it prints out the first 5 rows of data.

I'm running Python 2.7 and it's in a virtualenv.

Thanks for any help in advance and the code is below:

```
import datetime
import pandas
from pandas_datareader import data

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 22)

df = data.DataReader("XOM", "google", start, end)

print df.head()
```

Error output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/lcc/virtualenv/matplotlib/pandas.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lcc/virtualenv/matplotlib/pandas.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/Users/lcc/virtualenv/matplotlib/pandas.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader import data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo, get_data_enigma,  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/google/daily.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas.compat as compat
ImportError: No module named compat

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Whats the pandas version you are using

Comment: pandas (0.21.0)

Comment: Try removing it and reinstall again. Maybe it aint installed properly. I have no errors when I tried to import compat from pandas

Comment: I've tried this but still no luck I'm afraid! Deleted and reinstalled both pandas and pandas-datareader.

Comment: If you have installed and trying on the go consider restarting the kernel once. That might help

Comment: have you saved your file with the name pandas.py ? If that is the case, rename your file name and it should work

Comment: Again still no luck on the above. I've restarted and renamed the file to exonmob.py.

The latest version of Pandas was released on Oct 27th. I've reverted back to the last released 0.19.2 and it's still not working. I have tried this on a different computer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is written in the error traceback:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas.compat as compat
```

`pandas_datareader/base.py` calls (imports) `pandas.compat`

you named your script `pandas.py` - that has shadowed the Pandas module and your script doesn't contain `compat`.

**Solution:**

Rename `/Users/lcc/virtualenv/matplotlib/pandas.py` to something that does NOT duplicate/shadow any of Python module names.

For example: `/Users/lcc/virtualenv/matplotlib/my_first_pandas_prog.py`

Comment: I've changed the file name but no luck. Although I have managed to get it to work, I've switched my editor from PyCharm to VSCode.  When I run the file in VS Code and also in IDLE, it works fine. Need to investigate further though as it could be my interpreter settings in PyCharm.

Comment: @Philpot, i could reproduce this error by putting your code into the script named "pandas.py". When i'm executing `python pandas.py` - it gives me the same error, when i rename this script - it works just fine. I would also rename your virtualenv...